# data to a v model ? do i have to initialize the data if its coming from another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prop, v-model

I am trying to put the value of `content` data from another component  in `this.newTutorial.content` push function.

so far I get the data now I need to put it inside my v-model, like putting data from a v-model to another v-model?  I tried this `this.newTutorial.content = this.content;` on the created function but no luck yet says type check failed for prop "rules". Expected Array, got Boolean with value true.

here is my code:

```
<style scoped>
img.preview {
  width:200px;
}
.v-btn {
    height: 50px !important;
    min-width: 50px !important;
}

</style>

<template>

<div id="app">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
        <template  v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn style="z-index:9;" color="blue lighten-1" dark rounded v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fixed left>
                <v-tooltip right >
                    <template  v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-icon fab dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                            mdi-plus
                        </v-icon>
                    </template>
                    <img class="monk-ico" src="https://celfonica.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/logos/monk-circle+50px.png">
                    <span style="display:inline;">
                      Add Tutorial
                    </span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <div class="left">
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="dialog = false" width="10px">
                <v-icon>
                    mdi-close
                </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Tutorial form</h1>
            <h3> create one</h3>
            <form id="form" class="form-inline" v-on:submit.prevent="addTutorial">
                <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                <h4>Author details</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="nameRules" required label="First Name" type="text" id="tutorialFirst" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.first">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="nameRules" required label="Last Name" type="text" id="tutorialLast" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.last">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="emailRules" required label="Email" type="text" id="tutorialEmail" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.email">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-goup">
                  <!-- Img upload input field-->
                  <div>
                    <h4 class="m-tb-20">Upload tutorial picture:</h4>
                  <input class="form-control"  type="file" @change="previewImage" accept="image/+">
                  <br><v-btn class="m-tb-20" @click=" onUpload();"><v-icon>mdi-upload</v-icon></v-btn>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p> Progress: {{uploadValue.toFixed()+"%"}}
                    <progress :value="uploadValue" max="100"></progress>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

                <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                <h4>Tutorial content</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-select required label="Language"
                    id="tutorialLanguage" v-model="newTutorial.language"
                    multiple type="text" autocomplete tags :items="languages" class="form-control">
                        <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                            <v-btn>
                                {{ data.item }}
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                    </v-select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="titleRules" required label="Tutorial Title" type="text" id="tutorialTitle" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.title">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
  <!--tiptap-->   <v-card >
                  <div >
                    <editor-menu-bar v-on:submit.prevent="addTutorial" :editor="editor" v-slot="{ commands, isActive }">
                      <div>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.bold() }" @click="commands.bold">
                      <v-icon class="mdi mdi-format-bold mdi-24px"> </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.italic() }" @click="commands.italic">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-format-italic mdi-24px "> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.underline() }" @click="commands.underline">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-format-underline mdi-24px "> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.code() }" @click="commands.code">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-code-tags mdi-24px "> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.link() }" @click="commands.link">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-link mdi-24px"> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>

                      <v-divider></v-divider>
                    </div>
                    </editor-menu-bar>
                    <editor-content  label="Tutorial content"  :editor="editor" v-model="content" />
                  </div>
                  </v-card>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field required label="Date" class="form-control" type='date' v-model='newTutorial.date'>
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field  required label="Tutorial Sample Code Link" type="url" id="tutorialCode" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.code">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>

              <div>

                <br>

              </div>
                <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                <h4> Preview </h4>
                <v-card class="m-tb-20" v-model="newTutorial">
                  <img class="preview " :src="picture"><br>
                    <v-card-title class="center">{{ newTutorial.title }} </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-subtitle> {{ newTutorial.first }} {{ newTutorial.last }} </v-card-subtitle>
                    <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                    <v-card-text>{{ newTutorial.content }}</v-card-text>
                     {{ content }}
                    <v-card-text>
                        <h5>{{ newTutorial.language }}</h5>
                        <h5>{{ newTutorial.email }}</h5>
                        <h5>{{ newTutorial.date }}</h5>
                    </v-card-text>

                </v-card>

                <!-- Form push btn -->
                <v-btn class="m-tb-20" @click="markcompleted();" type="submit" small color="primary" dark>
                    {{ displayText }}
                </v-btn>
            </form>
        </div>
    </v-dialog>
</div>

</template>

<script>

import firebase from '../plugins/firebase'
import EditorContent from "../components/EditorContent";
import toastr from 'toastr';
// to debug multiple Fire apps
//if (!firebase.apps.length) {
//    firebase.initializeApp(config);
//    this.newTutorial.userID= uid;
//}
import { Editor,  EditorMenuBar } from 'tiptap'
import {
  Blockquote,
  CodeBlock,
  HardBreak,
  Heading,
  OrderedList,
  BulletList,
  ListItem,
  TodoItem,
  TodoList,
  Bold,
  Code,
  Italic,
  Link,
  Strike,
  Underline,
  History,
} from 'tiptap-extensions'

let db = firebase.database();

let messagesRef = db.ref('tutorials');

export default {
    name: 'tutform',
    firebase: {
        tutorials: messagesRef
    },
    components: {
      EditorMenuBar,
      EditorContent,
    },
    data() {
        return {
          content: null,
          editor: new Editor({
            extensions: [
              new Blockquote(),
              new CodeBlock(),
              new HardBreak(),
              new Heading({ levels: [1, 2, 3] }),
              new BulletList(),
              new OrderedList(),
              new ListItem(),
              new TodoItem(),
              new TodoList(),
              new Bold(),
              new Code(),
              new Italic(),
              new Link(),
              new Strike(),
              new Underline(),
              new History(),
            ],
            content: '',
            }),
            imageData:null,
            picture:null,
            uploadValue: 0,
            dialog: false,
            displayText: 'Push me!',
            newTutorial: {
                first: '',
                email: '',
                last: '',
                language: [],
                title: '',
                content: '',
                date: '',
                picture:'',
                code: '',
            },
            languages: [
                'Html', 'CSS', 'VUE', 'React', 'Ruby', 'JS', 'SASS', 'Python','PHP','C#','JAVA','Other',
            ],
            nameRules: [
                v => !!v || 'you must type something',
                v => v.length <= 10 || 'hum.. this monk smelling somthing strange... must be less than 10 characters',
            ],
            emailRules: [
                v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
                v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Please enter a valid email containing @ ',
            ],
            contentRules: [
                v => !!v || 'Content is required amigo!'
            ],
            titleRules: [
                v => !!v || 'Tittle is required buddy!',
                v => v.length <= 100 || 'Woots!, Lets try making this one shorter'
            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {
        previewImage(event){
            this.uploadValue=0;
            this.picture=null;
            this.imageData=event.target.files[0];
        },
        onUpload() {
          this.picture=null;
          const storageRef=firebase.storage().ref(`tutorials/images/${this.imageData.name}`).put(this.imageData);
          storageRef.on(`state_changed`, snapshot=>{
            this.uploadValue=(snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
          }, error=>{console.log(error.message)},
          ()=>{this.uploadValue=100;
          storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
            this.picture=url;
            this.newTutorial.picture = url;
            console.log(this.picture);
            toastr.success('Image Uploaded successfully');
          })}
        )
        },
        addTutorial: function() {
            messagesRef.child(this.newTutorial.userID).push(this.newTutorial);
            this.newTutorial.first = '';
            this.newTutorial.last = '';
            this.newTutorial.content = '';
            this.newTutorial.email = '';
            this.newTutorial.language = '';
            this.newTutorial.title = '';
            this.newTutorial.date = '',
            this.newTutorial.picture= '',
            this.newTutorial.code= '',
            toastr.success('Horray! message sent successfully');
            this.displayText = 'Nice job!';
            this.nameRules = true;
            this.emailRules = true;
            this.contentRules = true;
            this.titleRules = true;
        },
        markcompleted: function() {
            this.displayText = 'hum.. somthing still missing';
        }
    },
    // this functions trow in uid from user in data valu to {uid}
    created: function(){
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var uid;
      if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid; // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                         // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                         // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
      }
      this.newTutorial.userID = uid;
      this.newTutorial.content = this.content;
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      this.editor.destroy()
    }
}

</script>
```

Then my component code for importing the content data :

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'EditorContent',
  props: {
    editor: {
      default: null,
      type: Object
    },
    value: {
      default: "",
      type: String
    }
  },

  watch: {
    editor: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(editor) {
        if (!editor || !editor.element) return;

        this.editor.setContent(this.value);
        this.editor.on("update", ({ getHTML }) => {
          this.$emit("input", getHTML());
        });

        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$el.appendChild(editor.element.firstChild);
          editor.setParentComponent(this);
        });
      }
    },
    value: {
      handler(value) {
        this.editor.setContent(value);
      }
    }
  },

  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("div");
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.editor.element = this.$el;
  }
};
</script>
```

vue data:

[image]

console error:

[image]

Comment: Lot of code to read over there, is it all really needed to demonstrate your issue? Can you please remove any html, styles, methods etc that are not directly related?

Comment: the error states something about `newEditor` being undefined ... but .. your code doesn't even reference that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to implement two-way binding with v-model on a custom element.

You will need to create a prop called `content`, then emit `input` events to the parent component. Check this sample code out:

Child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="date-picker">
    Month: <input type="number" ref="monthPicker" :value="value.month" @input="updateDate()"/>
    Year: <input type="number" ref="yearPicker" :value="value.year" @input="updateDate()"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],

  methods: {
    updateDate() {
      this.$emit('input', {
        month: +this.$refs.monthPicker.value,
        year: +this.$refs.yearPicker.value
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <date-picker v-model="date"></date-picker>
    <p>
      Month: {{date.month}}
      Year: {{date.year}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from './DatePicker.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DatePicker
  },

  data() {
    return {
      date: {
        month: 1,
        year: 2017
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

For more information, check out this [short article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-add-v-model-support)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove my content v-model inside the editor content tag and add the v-model I had made for sending the tutorials. here is the working code.

code:

```
<template>
<div>
<editor-content  label="Tutorial content"  :editor="editor" v-model="newTutorial.content" />
</div>
</template>
```

inside the script in my data :

```
 newTutorial: {
                first: '',
                email: '',
                last: '',
                language: [],
                title: '',
                content: '',
                date: '',
                picture:'',
                code: '',
            },
```

inside the script in my send funciton :

```
addTutorial: function() {
            messagesRef.child(this.newTutorial.userID).push(this.newTutorial);
            this.newTutorial.first = '';
            this.newTutorial.last = '';
            this.newTutorial.content = '';
            this.newTutorial.email = '';
            this.newTutorial.language = '';
            this.newTutorial.title = '';
            this.newTutorial.date = '',
            this.newTutorial.picture= '',
            this.newTutorial.code= '',
            toastr.success('Horray! message sent successfully');
            this.displayText = 'Nice job!';
            this.nameRules = true;
            this.emailRules = true;
            this.contentRules = true;
            this.titleRules = true;
        },
```

data in db :

[image]

form component code:

```
<style scoped>
img.preview {
  width:200px;
}
.v-btn {
    height: 50px !important;
    min-width: 50px !important;
}

</style>

<template>

<div id="app">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
        <template  v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn style="z-index:9;" color="blue lighten-1" dark rounded v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fixed left>
                <v-tooltip right >
                    <template  v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-icon fab dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                            mdi-plus
                        </v-icon>
                    </template>
                    <img class="monk-ico" src="https://celfonica.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/logos/monk-circle+50px.png">
                    <span style="display:inline;">
                      Add Tutorial
                    </span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <div class="left">
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="dialog = false" width="10px">
                <v-icon>
                    mdi-close
                </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Tutorial form</h1>
            <h3> create one</h3>
            <form id="form" class="form-inline" v-on:submit.prevent="addTutorial">
                <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                <h4>Author details</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="nameRules" required label="First Name" type="text" id="tutorialFirst" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.first">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="nameRules" required label="Last Name" type="text" id="tutorialLast" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.last">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="emailRules" required label="Email" type="text" id="tutorialEmail" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.email">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-goup">
                  <!-- Img upload input field-->
                  <div>
                    <h4 class="m-tb-20">Upload tutorial picture:</h4>
                  <input class="form-control"  type="file" @change="previewImage" accept="image/+">
                  <br><v-btn class="m-tb-20" @click=" onUpload();"><v-icon>mdi-upload</v-icon></v-btn>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p> Progress: {{uploadValue.toFixed()+"%"}}
                    <progress :value="uploadValue" max="100"></progress>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

                <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                <h4>Tutorial content</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-select required label="Language"
                    id="tutorialLanguage" v-model="newTutorial.language"
                    multiple type="text" autocomplete tags :items="languages" class="form-control">
                        <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                            <v-btn>
                                {{ data.item }}
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                    </v-select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field :rules="titleRules" required label="Tutorial Title" type="text" id="tutorialTitle" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.title">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
  <!--tiptap-->   <v-card >
                  <div >
                    <editor-menu-bar v-on:submit.prevent="addTutorial" :editor="editor" v-slot="{ commands, isActive }">
                      <div>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.bold() }" @click="commands.bold">
                      <v-icon class="mdi mdi-format-bold mdi-24px"> </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.italic() }" @click="commands.italic">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-format-italic mdi-24px "> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.underline() }" @click="commands.underline">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-format-underline mdi-24px "> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.code() }" @click="commands.code">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-code-tags mdi-24px "> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.link() }" @click="commands.link">
                        <v-icon class="mdi mdi-link mdi-24px"> </v-icon>
                      </v-btn>

                      <v-divider></v-divider>
                    </div>
                    </editor-menu-bar>
                    <editor-content  label="Tutorial content"  :editor="editor" v-model="newTutorial.content" />
                  </div>
                  </v-card>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field required label="Date" class="form-control" type='date' v-model='newTutorial.date'>
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <v-text-field  required label="Tutorial Sample Code Link" type="url" id="tutorialCode" class="form-control" v-model="newTutorial.code">
                    </v-text-field>
                </div>

              <div>

                <br>

              </div>
                <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                <h4> Preview </h4>
                <v-card class="m-tb-20" v-model="newTutorial">
                  <img class="preview " :src="picture"><br>
                    <v-card-title class="center">{{ newTutorial.title }} </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-subtitle> {{ newTutorial.first }} {{ newTutorial.last }} </v-card-subtitle>
                    <v-divider class="m-tb-20"></v-divider>
                    <v-card-text>{{ newTutorial.content }}</v-card-text>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <h5>{{ newTutorial.language }}</h5>
                        <h5>{{ newTutorial.email }}</h5>
                        <h5>{{ newTutorial.date }}</h5>
                    </v-card-text>

                </v-card>

                <!-- Form push btn -->
                <v-btn class="m-tb-20" @click="markcompleted();" type="submit" small color="primary" dark>
                    {{ displayText }}
                </v-btn>
            </form>
        </div>
    </v-dialog>
</div>

</template>

<script>

import firebase from '../plugins/firebase'
import EditorContent from "../components/EditorContent";
import toastr from 'toastr';
// to debug multiple Fire apps
//if (!firebase.apps.length) {
//    firebase.initializeApp(config);
//    this.newTutorial.userID= uid;
//}
import { Editor,  EditorMenuBar } from 'tiptap'
import {
  Blockquote,
  CodeBlock,
  HardBreak,
  Heading,
  OrderedList,
  BulletList,
  ListItem,
  TodoItem,
  TodoList,
  Bold,
  Code,
  Italic,
  Link,
  Strike,
  Underline,
  History,
} from 'tiptap-extensions'

let db = firebase.database();

let messagesRef = db.ref('tutorials');
export default {
    name: 'tutform',
    firebase: {
        tutorials: messagesRef
    },
    components: {
      EditorMenuBar,
      EditorContent,
    },
    data() {
        return {
          editor: new Editor({
            extensions: [
              new Blockquote(),
              new CodeBlock(),
              new HardBreak(),
              new Heading({ levels: [1, 2, 3] }),
              new BulletList(),
              new OrderedList(),
              new ListItem(),
              new TodoItem(),
              new TodoList(),
              new Bold(),
              new Code(),
              new Italic(),
              new Link(),
              new Strike(),
              new Underline(),
              new History(),
            ],
            content: '',
            }),
            imageData:null,
            picture:null,
            uploadValue: 0,
            dialog: false,
            displayText: 'Push me!',
            newTutorial: {
                first: '',
                email: '',
                last: '',
                language: [],
                title: '',
                content: '',
                date: '',
                picture:'',
                code: '',
            },
            languages: [
                'Html', 'CSS', 'VUE', 'React', 'Ruby', 'JS', 'SASS', 'Python','PHP','C#','JAVA','Other',
            ],
            nameRules: [
                v => !!v || 'you must type something',
                v => v.length <= 10 || 'hum.. this monk smelling somthing strange... must be less than 10 characters',
            ],
            emailRules: [
                v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
                v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Please enter a valid email containing @ ',
            ],
            contentRules: [
                v => !!v || 'Content is required amigo!'
            ],
            titleRules: [
                v => !!v || 'Tittle is required buddy!',
                v => v.length <= 100 || 'Woots!, Lets try making this one shorter'
            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {
        previewImage(event){
            this.uploadValue=0;
            this.picture=null;
            this.imageData=event.target.files[0];
        },
        onUpload() {
          this.picture=null;
          const storageRef=firebase.storage().ref(`tutorials/images/${this.imageData.name}`).put(this.imageData);
          storageRef.on(`state_changed`, snapshot=>{
            this.uploadValue=(snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
          }, error=>{console.log(error.message)},
          ()=>{this.uploadValue=100;
          storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
            this.picture=url;
            this.newTutorial.picture = url;
            console.log(this.picture);
            toastr.success('Image Uploaded successfully');
          })}
        )
        },
        addTutorial: function() {
            messagesRef.child(this.newTutorial.userID).push(this.newTutorial);
            this.newTutorial.first = '';
            this.newTutorial.last = '';
            this.newTutorial.content = '';
            this.newTutorial.email = '';
            this.newTutorial.language = '';
            this.newTutorial.title = '';
            this.newTutorial.date = '',
            this.newTutorial.picture= '',
            this.newTutorial.code= '',
            toastr.success('Horray! message sent successfully');
            this.displayText = 'Nice job!';
            this.nameRules = true;
            this.emailRules = true;
            this.contentRules = true;
            this.titleRules = true;
        },
        markcompleted: function() {
            this.displayText = 'hum.. somthing still missing';
        }
    },
    // this functions trow in uid from user in data valu to {uid}
    created: function(){
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var uid;
      if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid; // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                         // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                         // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
      }
      this.newTutorial.userID = uid;
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      this.editor.destroy()
    }
}

</script>
```

child component:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'EditorContent',
  props: {
    editor: {
      default: null,
      type: Object
    },
    value: {
      default: "",
      type: String
    }
  },

  watch: {
    editor: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(editor) {
        if (!editor || !editor.element) return;

        this.editor.setContent(this.value);
        this.editor.on("update", ({ getHTML }) => {
          this.$emit("input", getHTML());
        });

        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$el.appendChild(editor.element.firstChild);
          editor.setParentComponent(this);
        });
      }
    },
    value: {
      handler(value) {
        this.editor.setContent(value);
      }
    }
  },

  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("div");
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.editor.element = this.$el;
  }
};
</script>
```

Hope it helps someone, I did this to add tip tap editor.